# Пояснение программы

Tags: pascal

Дана последовательность целых чисел а1,а2,...,а18, в начале которой записаны несколько равных между собой элементов. Определить количество таких элементов последовательности. Условный оператор и массивы не использовать. Использовать оператор цикла с условием.

```
program reflect;
var s, k, n, m: integer;
begin
  readln(s);
  n := 1;
  repeat
    readln(k);
    m := n;
    while (s = k) and (n = m) do inc(n)
  until (s <> k) or (n >= 18);
  for m := n + 1 to 17 do readln(s);
  writeln;
  writeln(n);
  readln
end.
```

Можете пожалуйста растолковать эту программу? по действиям)

Comment: В 9-й строке побывал мастер) Там написано `if s=k then inc(n)`

Comment: Ещё можно `while (s=k) do begin inc(n); break; end;`

Answer (score 1):

```
program reflect;
var s, k, n, m: integer;
begin
  readln(s); //считывает число введённое с клавиатуры
  n := 1;
  repeat
    readln(k); //считывает второе число пока не выйдет из цикла
    m := n; //
    while (s = k) and (n = m) do inc(n) //пока последующие числа равны первому увеличивает (inc) счётчик n на +1.  (n = m) нужен для выхода  из этого цикла. 
  until (s <> k) or (n >= 18); //выход из цикла если следующее число неравно первому или введено 17 раз
  for m := n + 1 to 17 do readln(s); //продолжить считывать ввод оостальных чисел но ничего с ними не делать
  writeln;
  writeln(n); //написать количество совпадений. количество введённых n совпадающих с s
  readln
end.
```